# Using global for database conection not working

Tags: php

Ok. Hello guys

I have some problems with my database connection and using it in php.

My normal file structure:

db.php

```
$mysql_server   = "server";
$mysql_user     = "user";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_db       = "name";

$db = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    exit();
}
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

functions.php file

```
require_once("db.php");

function func_name() {
     global $db;
     //doing my work here with $db;
}
```

I'm 100% sure the credentials i user are ok so this is not the problem.

Can you give me some advice regarding this? I used this structure for every project and now i'm losing my mind trying to figure it out. I bet is something that i missed!

please, help! Thank you!

Comment: you forget to tell us about error message

Comment: its no good handling to use *global* => better use function func_name($db), 2. in db.php you call an *exit()* function ... echo something when it went wrong, or better throw Exeption

Comment: Please update your question with the output that is happening when you say "not working". There isn't enough information in your question for us to do anything more than speculate. Is there an error message on screen/in logs? Does it `exit()`? Did you accidentally overwrite $db in the global scope somewhere?

Comment: It seems i was having just a problem with how i was including files. Now i try to find best way to have files available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

try using below code !!!

```
<?php
$mysql_server  = "localhost";
$mysql_user    = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_db      = "dbName";

$db = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);
if ($db->connect_errno)
{
    exit();
}
$db->set_charset("utf8");


function func_name() {
  global $db;
  $sql = "SELECT text FROM tableName";
  $result = $db->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $row["columnName"];
    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
}

func_name();
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```